# Uncaught TypeError: d.type.toUpperCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, python, json

so I'm trying to send data as a json to a Python file, however my Python I'm getting the error

Uncaught TypeError: d.type.toUpperCase is not a function

I'm a newbie to JS so I'm not sure how everything fully works, however I did just add in the `GET` by the `POST` because before that I was getting `405` errors.

Now, I'm getting this `d.type.toUpperCase` error. Here is my code. Please help!!

JavaScript:

```
function on_request_success(response) {
    console.debug('response', response);
    document.write("Success!!!");
} 

function on_request_error(r, text_status, error_thrown) {
    console.log(r);
    console.debug('error' + text_status + ", " + error_thrown + ":\n" + r.responseText);
    document.write("Failure line 11");
}

var request = {"Data":"Success!!"};

function addTrack() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://mattprice09.github.io/addTrack.py',
    type:  ['GET','POST'],
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(request),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    success: on_request_success,
    error: on_request_error
});
}
```

Python:

```
import json
import sys

request = json.load(sys.stdin)

file_open = open('http://mattprice09.github.io/database.txt', a)
file.write(request)
file.close()
```

Comment: You can't open a URL for writing to; that's not a file. Not that that causes the error you posted, the Python code you posted cannot raise it. What is the *full* traceback of the exception? Are you sure you are calling the right URL?

Comment: Besides, github.io hosting doesn't allow for Python scripts, so `http://mattprice09.github.io/addTrack.py` is certainly not executed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll figure out how to open a url instead of file. The full stack is: f.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
addTrack @ tester.js:17
(anonymous function) @ index.html:12

Comment: The `type` parameter for the `$.ajax` call is also not supposed to be a list, I think. Too many things are badly broken here.

Comment: Ah, and that's exactly why you get the error, it is a JS error telling you a list cannot be uppercased..

Comment: Crap, alright. Thanks. I clearly have no idea what I'm doing...

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `type` argument to a string, not a list:

```
type: 'POST',
```

From the [`$.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **type** (default: `'GET'`)
>   Type: String
>   An alias for `method`. You should use `type` if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

The error tells you that a list cannot be uppercased.

However, you'll have other major issues here:

- GitHub pages doesn't support server-side scripts. Your Python code is not going to be executed.
- You cannot open a remote URL for writing; the `open()` function can only open files on the local filesystem.

Comment: Oh, wow. Alright. I've been having trouble for hours trying to figure out a way to read/write from a .txt file. The catch is that the file needs to be able to be read/written to from multiple users at once. I figured Python would be best as a middle man. Will I be able to run the Python script if I upload it elsewhere?

Comment: @Matt: you'll need to do more work to handle concurrency if you want multiple users to be able to write to it (think locking or even switching to a database). The script will not directly work; you'll need to tie it into whatever system you are using to talk to the web. Perhaps take a look at frameworks like [Flask](flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/), and find yourself a hoster that can do WSGI. Heroku can, Google App Engine can, Amazon Cloud can, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So .txt files won't work at all because of concurrency issues?

Comment: If two processes opened the file at the same time you'd get unexpected results. You could use file locking, but that doesn't really scale.

Comment: Our scale size is ~500.

Comment: @Matt: Per what time period? Beyond a handful it already can lead to growing delays. It's easier to just delegate that headache to something like `sqlite`, the bundled embedded database.

Comment: Gotcha...I've spent the last four hours setting up MongoDB with the Java plug-in. I have it set up, but now I just need to figure out exactly how to run java .class files in HTML or JS.